# Undefined Reference for 1 of many constructors for QVideoFrame

Tags: c++, qt, linker, ffmpeg

I've come across a weird issue while trying to convert an FFMPeg `AVFrame` to a QT `QVideoFrame`;

I'm trying to create the `QVideoFrame` using this constructor

```
QVideoFrame(int bytes, const QSize &size, int bytesPerLine, PixelFormat format);
```

It compiles fine, however at link I receive the issue;

```
~myfile.cpp:130: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QVideoFrameC1EiRK5QSizeiNS_13AVPixelFormatE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(As it's a linker issue, I'm presuming you won't want code examples).

I've compiled QT 4.8.5 myself using `mingw32` and the other constructors (no params and `QImage` param) for `QVideoFrame` that I've tested compile and link correctly. From looking at the QT sources there is nothing that stands out as different for this constructor for it to not be included in the library.

At this point I'm trying to implement an extension of `QAbstractVideoBuffer` so I can use that constructor, however that's proving harder than it should be & I'd love to understand why this issue is occurring.

Thanks

Comment: I've now traced the error so far to find that it's caused by one of my ffmpeg imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of messing with this, I traced the issue to the inclusion of the ffmpeg headers that was causing the issue. By placing the ffmpeg header includes after all the QT header includes and then undeffing a stray #def that conflicted with the QT classes, it now compiles!